# .NET regex replace using backreference

Tags: c#, regex

I have a fairly long string that contains sub strings with the following format:

```
project[1]/someword[1]
project[1]/someotherword[1]
```

There will be about 10 or so instances of this pattern in the string.

What I want to do is to be able to replace the second integer in square brackets with a different one. So the string would look like this for instance:

```
project[1]/someword[2]
project[1]/someotherword[2]
```

I''m thinking that regular expressions are what I need here. I came up with the regex:

```
project\[1\]/.*\[([0-9])\]
```

Which should capture the group [0-9] so I can replace it with something else. I'm looking at MSDN Regex.Replace() but I'm not seeing how to replace part of a string that is captured with a value of your choosing. Any advice on how to accomplish this would be appreciated. Thanks much.

**Edit: ** After working with @Tharwen some I have changed my approach a bit. Here is the new code I am working with:

```
  String yourString = String yourString = @"<element w:xpath=""/project[1]/someword[1]""/> <anothernode></anothernode> <another element w:xpath=""/project[1]/someotherword[1]""/>";
 int yourNumber = 2;
 string anotherString = string.Empty;
 anotherString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(?<=project\[1\]/.*\[)\d(?=\]"")", yourNumber.ToString());
```

Comment: Is the word "project" always going to be in each string?

Comment: Silly me, I didn't read your regex properly - I can see that yes, it is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've adapted yours to use a lookbehind and lookahead to only match a digit which is preceded by 'project[1]/xxxxx[' and followed by ']':

```
(?<=project\[1\]/.*\[)\d(?=\]")
```

Then, you can use:

```
String yourString = "project[1]/someword[1]";
int yourNumber = 2;
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(?<=project\[1\]/.*\[)\d(?=\]"")", yourNumber.ToString());
```

I think maybe you were confused because Regex.Replace has lots of overloads which do slightly different things. I've used [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. You are correct about me getting a bit confused with the overloads, however running your code throws the following exception : "Argument 3 cannot convert from "method group" to "string" . I saw this exception myself when I was playing around with this and trying to get it to work.

Comment: @TheMethod Whoops, I missed the brackets on ToString. That's what I get for not actually running the code before posting it...

Comment: Sheesh I should have saw that myself anyway. Thanks much for the help. I am still getting an issue, and that is if the string is ""project[1]/someword[1] more text "project[1]/someotherword[1]"" I will end up with  project[1]/someword[2] more text "project[2]/someotherword[2] , I don't want project[num] to ever change it should always be 1. Do you know how to remedy this?

Comment: Oh, I see. The .* is running on to the next instance. We need something that is always between the strings that we can stop the parser at. Whitespace, perhaps?

Comment: Hmm well the string that I am doing the search and replace on is XML. The /project[1]/sometext[0] is xpath syntax. So it looks like this <some element w:xpath="/project[1]/theword[1]"/>  . There is always "/>" after the part I want to replace.

Comment: @TheMethod  
Looking at that, I think it would be best to use the double quotes to stop the parser, since they can never appear in the string. I've updated the answer to do that, so please let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks again for the responses, I really appreciate it. Now it doesn't seem to modify the string at all, the regex is not picking up anything.

Comment: @TheMethod Oh yeah, it's not assigning the return value to the string... What else have I forgotten, I wonder?

Comment: Not sure, I've been playing around with it for awhile now but having no luck.

Comment: @TheMethod Can you update your question with the code you have right now?

Comment: @TheMethod The Regex assumes that project[1]/someword[1] will be in quotes, but `yourString` doesn't have any in it. You can put them in the string by escaping them with \, if you need to.

Comment: Gah - brain fart - I've updated the code to use a string in the expected format. It looks like the regex is doing what it is supposed to. Thanks much, I really appreciate all the help you gave me here.

Answer (score 32):

Matched groups are replaced using the $1, $2 syntax as follows :-

```
csharp> Regex.Replace("Meaning of life is 42", @"([^\d]*)(\d+)", "$1($2)");
"Meaning of life is (42)"
```

If you are new to regular expressions in .NET I recommend http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Also http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html has some good stuff for quick reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the syntax for coding a backreference into a replacement string, which I wasn't finding elsewhere. Also, your second reference is one of my go-to sites for reminders and cheat sheets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the value of a captured group before replacing it, you'll have to separate the different parts of the string, make your modifications and put them back together.

```
string test = "project[1]/someword[1]\nproject[1]/someotherword[1]\n";

string result = string.Empty;
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(test, @"(project\[1\]/.*\[)([0-9])(\]\n)"))
{
    result += match.Groups[1].Value;
    result += (int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value) + 1).ToString();
    result += match.Groups[3].Value;
}
```

If you just want to replace text verbatim, it's easier: `Regex.Replace(test, @"abc(.*)cba", @"cba$1abc")`.

Answer (score -3):

you can use String.Replace (String, String)
for example

```
String.Replace ("someword[1]", "someword[2]")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This will not do what I need as the word will be variable. What I need to be able to do is capture the number in square brackets after someword and replace it with a different number.